# When : 1. time marker / 2. and it was the moment

Tags: conjunctions

> I had just arrived at the hotel ***when*** I remembered that I had left my keys in the office.

Here, when means "and it was the moment that~", so it means,

> I had just arrived at the hotel ***and it was the moment that*** I remembered that I had left my keys in the office.

But how about this?

> I had gotten used to coffee ***when*** I was in Brazil.

Here, when means during, which is just a ***time marker*** letting us know when the main clause happened. So, this means,

> I had gotten used to coffee ***during*** in Brazil.

So, here **when** means two different things:

*1: and it was the moment that*

*2: during*(time marker)

So, I'd like to know what's going on here with the conjunction ***when***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Context, context, context! . . . No word means anything outside of its context.

*When* doesn't really have two "meanings" in your sentences, but an overriding sense of something like *at the time that*. The contrast you observe, between a duration and a point in time, is imposed by the context—specifically, the [aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) of the verb involved.

- *Remember* in *remembered that I had left my keys* is "punctual"—an event which occurs at a point in time, so here *when* refers to that point.
- *Was* in *I was in Brazil* is "durational"—a state which endures over a period of time, so here *when* refers to that duration.

Note, by the way, that verbal aspect is also context-dependent: tense, aspect and modality are really properties of utterances, not words, and we select different verb forms and constructions to reflect ("agree with") the underlying situation spoken of.

Comment: It would be great if you could give us some example sentences.

Comment: @jihoon Examples of what?